# Call UserControl function from Page's Page_Load event

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, code-behind, pageload, findcontrol

I have a `UserControl` that functions as a template for a `FormView`, But depending on whether it is in edit or insert mode, one of the `TextBox` controls needs to be disabled. I added a function to the `UserControl`

```
public bool IsInsert
{
    get { return txtUser.Enabled; }
    set { txtUser.Enabled = value; }
}
```

But I cannot get a reference of the `UserControl` in the parent's `Page_Load` event. I defined the control in the aspx code (not code-behind). I've tries using `FindControl` but I get an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. Is this because the `UserControl` loads after the page? Is there another method of disabling the `TextBox` conditionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not good practice - `User Control` should decide this kind of stuff alone...

But if it need to be done this way:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitYouUserControl();
}
```

*Update:*

You have to wait till the `load event` of your `User Control` is fired.

And to access some parts of `User Control` you should define a property in it.

Comment: I would dislike using it if it isn't good practice... Is there a better solution than using a `User Control` or coding each `FormView` template individually?

Comment: @Pyitoechito - updated my answer. If it helpful - upvote it please ) If it is the solution for your question - also accept it

Comment: @Pyitoechito - do you know how to define property?

Comment: I decided to not use a `UserControl` or `FormView`for my current task. Thanks though.